# Add a sum by font color to the end of each column with excel vba

Tags: vba, excel

Need to sum by font color some columns. I only have the code above that of course sums everything.

```
Sub sum()
With Sheets("sheet4").Range("a1").CurrentRegion
    If .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).Value <> "Total" Then
        With .Offset(.Rows.Count).Resize(1)
            .Formula = "=sum(r2c:r[-1]c)"
            .Columns(1).Value = "Total"
        End With
    End If
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: There is not really enough information here to help you.

Comment: I ve a worksheet that is a report automatically created with column A that is a select of unique values of all the sheets in the workbook and sumif´s(included in the macro) of this unique values in columns B,C,D and E. In some of this unique values they have a green font color and the need is to have a sub total of the values that have green font leters and another sub-total of the values that have black font numbers automatically(inside the macro).

Answer (score 2):

If you need to iterate through a range and do something by font color, you could do something like the following. To use it, you will need to pass it the range you want to look through, and a range which has the font color you want to look for in it. This is easier than having to enter the full color number for the shade of green you want to look for - just copy a green fonted cell to another sheet, and pass that in as the parameter.

```
Sub DoSomethingByFontColor(ByRef xlRange As Excel.Range, ByRef checkColorrange As Excel.Range)

Dim xlcell As Excel.Range, i as long

For Each xlcell In xlRange
    If xlcell.Font.Color = checkColorrange.Font.Color Then
        'do something
        i = i + 1
    End If
Next xlcell

Debug.Print "There were " & i & "incidences of font color " & _
checkColorrange.Font.Color & " in the check range."

End Sub

Sub test()

DoSomethingByFontColor Sheet1.Range("C1:C5"), Sheet1.Range("a1")

End Sub
```